# Unable to get token from Youtube

Tags: youtube-api, token

We're trying to integrate the Youtube API on our server. But when we try to upload a video, we're getting a problem connecting to http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken.  The error states, `ERROR Unable to connect to tcp://gdata.youtube.com:80. Error #110: Connection timed out HTTP details`.

Why does this error occur, and how can we fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This might have been a temporary error due to server issues at YouTube. If that wasn't the case, and you can still reproduce the error, then there's something amiss with your network setup. The YouTube API servers should be operating properly right now and they don't intentionally refuse incoming network connections under any circumstances—at the very least, you will always get back a HTTP error response from an active server.

Answer (score 0):

Try making it a secure connection

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken
```

Comment: If you are saying to connect using HTTPS rather than HTTP, I think this is an actual answer.

Comment: @Pokechu22 Thank you. For the other two, this is not a link to an answer. I changed the author's link so it would work properly. Please read the whole thread before commenting.